# How to use `long` class names in Hugo/Pygments

Tags: hugo, pygments

I am using the `pygmentsUseClasses=true` setting on the Hugo Server but i'm receiving short class names like  `k` for `keyword`.

What i want;

`<span class="token keyword">const</span>`

What i have ;

`<span class="k">const</span>`

What is missing?

Answer (score 0):

I just wandered by on an unrelated search, but if anybody else has this question (confirmed as of 2020-01-19, but Hugo is a moving target):

1. `k` *is* the class name.
   Without classes enabled, you get inline styles in HTML output.
   Ex: `<span style="color:#66d9ef">const</span>`
2. Hugo uses [Chroma](https://github.com/alecthomas/chroma) instead of Pygments for [syntax highlighting](https://gohugo.io/content-management/syntax-highlighting/) now, which surely means that eventually `pygmentsUseClasses` will not be recognized. The [current documented configuration](https://gohugo.io/getting-started/configuration-markup#highlight) is `markup.highlight.noClasses`:

   ```
   [markup.highlight]
   noClasses = false # instead of pygmentsUseClasses = true
   ```
3. *(the actual answer to the actual question)* I see no Hugo configuration to generate long class names in HTML output.

Some [external helpers](https://gohugo.io/content-management/formats/#external-helpers) use their own highlighters. These may produce long file names, though it varies by helper. For example, my RST content results in long class names, but my AsciiDoc content does not. If you absolutely must have long class names, try an external helper.

**Warning:** external helpers affect build time. And like all non-core behavior, there is a risk of deprecation in future Hugo releases.